# R language-read the value in excel and check

Tags: r, excel

I am new to R language.
I have a dataset, the first column is the name and second is the value.
I want to read each value in the second column and check if the value falls into a certain range.

For example,

```
Name value
AA    123
```

and the range in (100,150)
which function can be used?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's customary around here to show what you have tried, and how it failed. Can you show us that?

Comment: `100 < df$value & value < df$150` (strict inequalities, since the nomenclature of your `(100,150)` suggests *open* ends ... perhaps I'm reading into that too much :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[i,2]<150){
    if(df[i,2]>100){
      print(df[i,])
    }
  }
}
```

that the **df** is your **dataset**

Comment: Hi, you might like to add a comment on what the output will be, and how that might meet the need of the original post (which to be fair was a little vague).

Comment: She wanted to filter her output based on the data in the second column so that if it were between 100 and 150, it would show the whole row. I did this with this simple code, Now she can put the output in a new ِdataset.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what the desired result is.

Option 1 could be a new column is created that records (e.g. TRUE/FALSE) whether an observation (row) is in the limits. For example, with tidyverse style code to create a column called "is_valid":

`df %>% mutate(is_valid = ...)`

Option 2 could be filtering the data to create a subset that has only the desired observations, e.g. with tidyverse style code.

`df %>% filter(value <= 150) %>% filter(value >= 100)`

In any case, I'd recommend spending some time to learn how to do this in a tidyverse way with dplyr (google the free online book R for Data Science).